# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the end of a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access

In this method I add the content of UITextFields, images and other strings in a sqlite database. Everything works fine. I mean, when i press the "Add" button, the "OK" image appear, the sound play and all the contents are added to the database (I can check restarting the application). But after all of this, I have this error in the "main.m"

This is the method:

```
-(IBAction)addItem:(id)sender { //gestione pulsante aggiunta elemento
    if (([itemNameField.text length] == 0) || ([priceField.text length] == 0) || ([priceField.text doubleValue] == 0.0) || ((incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex != 0) && (incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex != 1))) {
        if ([itemNameField.text length] == 0) {
        statusLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Specificare un nome."];
        } else if (([priceField.text length] == 0) || ([priceField.text doubleValue] == 0.0)) {
            statusLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Specificare un prezzo."];
        } else if ((incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex != 0) && (incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex != 1)) {
            statusLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Specificare \"Income/Outcome\" ."];            
        }
        if (!categoriaLabel.hidden) {
            [self hideThemAll];
        }
        [incomeOutcome setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1];
        statusLabel.hidden = NO;
        error = true;
        [self playSound];
        [ok setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"error.png"]];
        ok.hidden = NO;
        return;
    }
    //apriamo il database
    sqlite3 *db;
    int dbrc; //Codice di ritorno del database (database return code)
    iWalletAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iWalletAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    const char *dbFilePathUTF8 = [appDelegate.dbFilePath UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_open(dbFilePathUTF8, &db);
    if (dbrc) {
        NSLog(@"Impossibile aprire il Database!");
        return;
    }
    //database aperto! Inseriamo valori nel database.
    sqlite3_stmt *dbps; //Istruzione di preparazione del database
    NSString *insertStatementsNS;
    if (incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        insertStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into \"shoppinglist\" (item, price, groupid, incout, path,  dateadded) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"Entrata\", %d, \"%@\", DATETIME('NOW'))", itemNameField.text, priceField.text, incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex, imagePath];
    } else if ([categoryNameField.text length] != 0) { 
        insertStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into \"shoppinglist\" (item, price, groupid, incout, path, dateadded) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", %d, \"%@\", DATETIME('NOW'))", itemNameField.text, priceField.text, categoryNameField.text, incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex, imagePath]; 
    } else { 
        insertStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into \"shoppinglist\" (item, price, groupid, incout, path, dateadded) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"Varie\", %d, \"%@\", DATETIME('NOW'))", itemNameField.text, priceField.text, incomeOutcome.selectedSegmentIndex, imagePath];
    }
    const char *insertStatement = [insertStatementsNS UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);
    dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbps);

    //faccio pulizia rilasciando i database
    sqlite3_finalize(dbps);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    // Pulisci i campi e indica successo nello status
    statusLabel.hidden = NO;
    statusLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Aggiunto %@", itemNameField.text];

    itemNameField.text = @"";
    priceField.text = @"";
    categoryNameField.text = @"";
    imagePath = @"";
    [incomeOutcome setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1];
    error = false;
    [self hideThemAll];
    [self playSound];
    [ok setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ok.png"]];
    ok.hidden = NO;
    nome = @"";
    prezzo =@"";
    [photoPreview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noPhoto.png"]];
    [[self parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Isaac I (maybe) found the issue: I wasn't retaining the picture I took from the camera.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    int r = arc4random() % 9999;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString *photoName = [dateNameFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    photoName = [photoName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", r]];

    if (imagePath) {
        [imagePath release];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", photoName]];
    [imagePath retain];

    UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ----- CODE FOR SCALE THE IMAGE ----- //
    if (picture.size.width == 1936) {
        picture = [picture scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(480.0f, 720.0f)];
    } else {
        picture = [picture scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(720.0f, 480.0f)];
    }

    photoPreview.image =  picture;

    photoPreview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    CGRect frame = photoPreview.frame;
    if (picture.size.width == 480) {
        frame.size.width = 111.3;
        frame.size.height =167;
    } else {
        frame.size.width = 167;
        frame.size.height =111.3;
    }
    photoPreview.frame = frame;
    // ----- ----- - END CODE - ----- ----- //    

    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture);
    CGImageRelease([picture CGImage]);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    [picture retain]; // <-- This little thing here!
    //imgPicker = nil;
}
```

Now it works! But if you can see other problems, please let me notice them.

Comment: Try to keep your methods under 20 lines of code at max, refactoring is key:)

Comment: By adding the [picture retain],  you will prevent your EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, but you also introduce a leak. I can give you more explanation if you'd like, but the simple answer is: Remove the CGImageRelease([picture CGImage]) because you didn't instantiate that, and then you can also remove the [picture retain], because you're over retaining. Removing *both* of those calls should balance your code (at least within the scope of this sample), preventing a BAD ACCESS or a leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically an EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when you are trying to access memory that has been deallocated. In your code sample, I don't see any [object release] calls (that's another problem entirely, unless you happen to be using ARC). But my guess it that this error is the result of a call that is being made outside of the scope of this method - something is being released prematurely.

You could paste your entire class, or, consider using the Instruments tool 'Zombies' to identify the dangling pointer which is (probably) causing this.

Comment: Ok. I used Zombies and I got this: `*** -[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x55dbe90` how do I know which pointer is referred?

Comment: "Not A Type" refers to a Core Foundation type. Are you assigning a CGImage to a layer somewhere? Again I suspect this issue it outside the scope of the sample you've posted; can you share more?

Comment: I edited my question with the piece of code I think was the problem. Now seems like it works. Can you please take a look?

Comment: See comment below your code sample. You've identified the source of the issue, but it needs a couple adjustments to be correct.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to create `NSString` like this:

```
 statusLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Specificare un nome."];
```

Simply write

```
statusLabel.text = @"Specificare un nome.";
```

Maybe it's not a cause of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but at least you can avoid several memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion isaac is right. I just want to add one guess. Most likely the error occurs when you invoke

```
[[self parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

By this moment, I think, something in you parentViewController is already released, so when you try to show it back, program turns to released variable and gives you a crash.

You can quite easily detect it just with the help of breakpoints.

Comment: That was was ok. I removed it and it still crash. I did as Isaac said. Used Zombie. But i don't know how to manage the response... can you help me?